# How to find highest root given my own functions of Bisection and Newton-Raphson

Tags: matlab

I've already created working functions in obtaining the root within a certain range or given a guess for bisection and n-r respectively. The problem tells me to find a root within 0.01% error of a function given (to the 3rd degree). It gives me a function with 3 roots and a range.

My take on this problem is to cut the range into 3 parts and find the roots between those ranges with the bisection method. But my bisection method only finds roots up to .5% error.

The problem allows me to graph it too.
Not sure how else to go about this. Thoughts?

Comment: Show some code please.

Comment: have you tried with `format long`. What I mean is: Are you sure that it is not the matlab displaying the values with 4 decimals that is the problem? If this is not the problem, may I see your termination condition?

Comment: What does it mean that "my bisection method only finds roots up to .5% error"? If this means what I think then tighten the stopping rule of your bisection solver.

Comment: `1e-4` isn't something hard to achieve with Matlab. If you are following your textbook in the _most straightforward_ way you won't have any problem in getting to this accuracy. Besides, your approach to cut up the domain is good; by "graph it" I think the problem asks you plot the function in the first place, so you can roughly locate the 3 zeros, thus making bisection easier.